# Characterize network camera stream

Tags: networking, stream, camera, vlc

I am trying to play a network camera stream in an application, but first I need to identify how to access the stream. Unfortunately, the manufacturer seems to prefer that I access the local web page of the camera and use it's built-in viewer, so there's no documentation on how to access the raw stream with another application.

For starters, I opened up the camera's web viewer and captured the connection traffic, trying to identify an address to point a player at. Here's the traffic that caught my attention: (IP edited)

```
GET http://127.0.0.1/mpeg4 HTTP/1.1\r\n
```

So I point Chrome (with VLC) at 127.0.0.1/mpeg4 and I get the VLC plugin. The tab is "busy" downloading but it never stops or plays the stream. My thought is that the plugin thinks the stream is a file, so it waits for end of file to play, which never comes.

Then I switched to VLC standalone and pointed it at the same address with the same results. No errors, but there's no buffering indicator or progress.

IE pointed to the address wants to download a file called mpeg4.mpeg from 127.0.0.1, but again it keeps downloading infinitely.

So with that backstory, my question is: **How can I detect exactly what this stream is and how to play it with VLC?**